# creating ruby extension for C++ library in C

Tags: c++, c, ruby, word-wrap

i was trying to build ruby extension for C++ library. first i did the wrapping C++ code into C. i build it using eclipse IDE and it works fine. then i try to build ruby extension for that  C source. here is the code i tried.

/*
 * Circle.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 18, 2013
 *      Author: kelum
 */

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H_
#define CIRCLE_H_

  namespace lemon{
class Circle {
    public:
        Circle(float radius):_radius(radius) {}
        float getArea() { return 3.14159 * _radius * _radius; }
   private:
        float _radius;

 };
}
```

/*
 * Circle_w.h
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 18, 2013
 *      Author: kelum
 */

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_W_H_
#define CIRCLE_W_H_

 #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
 #endif

    extern void *Circle_C_new(float radius);
    extern void  *Circle_C_delete(void *circle);
    extern float Circle_C_getArea(void *circle);

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif

#endif /* CIRCLE_W_H_ */
```

/*
 * Circle_w.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 18, 2013
 *      Author: kelum
 */

```
#include "Circle_w.h"
#include "Circle.h"
using namespace lemon;

extern void *Circle_C_new(float radius) {
       return new Circle(radius);
 }

 extern void *Circle_C_delete(void *circle) {
    Circle *c = (Circle *)circle;
   //delete c;
    return c;
 }

 extern float Circle_C_getArea(void *circle) {
    Circle *c = (Circle *)circle;
    return c->getArea();
 }
```

the main.c

```
#include "Circle_w.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float radius = 1.5;

    // Get a pointer to a Circle object
    void *circle = Circle_C_new(radius);

    // Pass the Circle object to the wrapper methods
    float area = Circle_C_getArea(circle);

    printf ("Circle of radius %f has area %f\n", radius, area);

    // Free the Circle object memory
    void *pointer=Circle_C_delete(circle);

    return 0;
}
```

this work fine. then i build C file using Circle_w.h header file.this the file.

```
#include "ruby.h"
#include "Circle_w.h"
#include <stdio.h>

extern VALUE method_test(){
float r=1.5;
void *circle = Circle_C_new(r);
int area = (int)Circle_C_getArea(circle);
printf("area %d \n",area);
return INT2NUM(area);
}

extern void Init_TestLemon() {
VALUE lemon = rb_define_module("TestLemon");
rb_define_method(lemon, "test", method_test, 0);
}
```

the extconf.rb file

```
require 'mkmf'
extension_name = 'TestLemon'
dir_config(extension_name)
create_makefile(extension_name)
```

and this is the ruby class i used to test module.

test.rb file

```
require '/home/kelum/workspace/Test/TestLemon'
include TestLemon
puts test
```

the problem is how can i compile this together? when i just run extconf.rb and test.rb it show error.

```
 TestLemon.so: undefined symbol: Circle_C_new
```

i think it is because extconf.rb don't execute the building of wrapping C++. how can i make this work? 
thanks very much.

Comment: Does your library here represent a separately installed dynamically-linkable lib, or source written in C++? If the former, you need to have it available as a library, and tell mkmf to use it. If the latter, then you need to have a copy of the .cpp file in the ext folder - is that where it is?

Comment: BTW, do you have a specific requirement to wrap in C as opposed to C++, it *is* possible to make the Ruby bindings in C++. Take a look at  RICE: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-extendruby/ - I've also had a hack at this: https://github.com/neilslater/ruby_nex_cpp

Comment: thank for your answers.i try to use source header files written in C++. in this this example Circle.h is the source written in C++. i just use it in same folder. i can't compile the wrapping with extconf.rb to make that test.o available for TestLemon.so. thaks again.

Comment: hi neil, i looked at your ruby_nex_cpp code. i couldn't understand the use of baz_vector_ruby.cpp and baz_vector_ruby.h. can you explain it little bit? i tried to do this in simple way. it show some error. i posted it here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368685/creating-ruby-c-extension. what are the problems with that implementation?

Comment: I've tried to answer your other question. Could you be more precise about what is confusing you in my files, I'm not sure what to explain? But basically my prototype gem shows *one way* to wrap a C++ class so that it is accessible in Ruby as if it were a Ruby class. If you want to do that a lot, I would recommend you take a look at RICE - my code works but is just a quick study on "how to do it", whilst RICE is a framework with many well-tested features.

Comment: ok. does it needed low-level ruby integration to use those objects like you did in baz_vector_ruby.cpp. can't we keep those objects(created by c++ code) as it is and access those objects via access methods which define in c++ code, from ruby? ,thank you very much for helping me.

Comment: That depends on the type of integration you want. If you want your C++ `Circle` class to appear in Ruby as a similar class, then you need the low-level integration (an allocation function and a delete function at minimum that Ruby can call for memory management - the rest are just "helpers" for my convenience). If you are happy, as in your Test module, to construct, use, and dispose of any C++ objects in a single call, then you don't really need that kind of integration.