# creating ruby C++ extension

Tags: c++, ruby

I created a sample ruby extension using C++ class. it works fine when i did not parse the value. but when i parse parameter it show an error. here is my code.

C++ header file

```
  #ifndef CIRCLE_H_
  #define CIRCLE_H_

class Circle {
    public:
        Circle(float radius):_radius(radius) {}
        float getArea() { return 3.14159 * _radius * _radius; }

    private:
        float _radius;

};
```

CPP file.

```
  #include<ruby.h>
  #include"Circle.h"

  VALUE method_test(VALUE y){
   double x= NUM2DBL(y);
   Circle *cir= new Circle(x);
   return DBL2NUM(cir->getArea());
  }

  extern "C" void Init_Test(){
   VALUE lemon = rb_define_module("Test");
   rb_define_method(lemon, "test", (VALUE(*)(ANYARGS))method_test,1);
  }
```

extconf.rb

```
    require 'mkmf'
    have_library( 'stdc++' );
    $CFLAGS << " -Wall"
    create_makefile( 'Test' );
```

run.rb

```
    require 'rubygems'

    require 'Test'

    include Test

    puts test(7)
```

when i execute run.rb it shows an error.

```
          run.rb:7:in `test': can't convert Object into Integer (TypeError)
          from run.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

please help me to solve this problem. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
VALUE method_test(VALUE y) {
```

Should be

```
VALUE method_test(VALUE self, VALUE y) {
```

The error message is thrown by `NUM2INT(y)` because `y` is the root `Object` of the script in your code as-is.  The root object is what you got because you mixed in your module at the top level of the script. If you had mixed in to another class, you would have got an instance of that class instead.

All native extension methods should take a `self` parameter (the first one if you have fixed number of params) which is the context that they are being called in (a `Module`, `Class` or instance of a `Class`). It is how you get `foo` into the extension when you call `foo.test`. This might seem odd when both Ruby and C++ do this automatically (`self` in Ruby, and `this` in C++): However it is necessary to have `self` appear as param because the Ruby internal API is written in C, which does not support OO directly - instead the Ruby API defined in `ruby.h` expects you to write and use C functions that take references to the current object as one of the params.

In addition you are making a call to `Circle( int radius )` - which does not exist (although the compiler may be kind and coerce `x` for you automatically). You probably want to use `double` variables throughout and use `NUM2DBL(y)` and `DBL2NUM( cir->getArea() )`

Comment: thanks a lot. that works.can you explain little bit about this root object? does it always needed specify root object? what does contain in this object? and thanks again for your good answer.

Comment: hi neil, do you know the way to call C++ constructors when class is define(when call new in ruby with various no of parameters)? I have several c++ constructors with initializing private members. how can i call those various constructors according to new(...) call in ruby?

Comment: @Kelum Deshapriya: Yes I do know a little about that, but the answer is not simple enough for a comment. Please ask a new question. Remember to follow usual SO guidelines - show one of the C++ constructors you want to call (not all of them please), and the relevant Ruby integration code you have for the class so far - have you created an `initialize` method yet - how about the memory allocation (an "alloc" method)?

Comment: thanks neil. i didn't try initialize method. now i tried it and it work fine. i thought having initialize method i have to call it separately after call new. but it override new as i wanted.thank you lot neil.